# Pattern matching a string in linear time

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

Given two strings S and T, where the T is the pattern string. Find if any scrambled form of pattern string exists as SubString in the string S and if present return the start index.

Example:

String S: abcdef
String T: efd

String S has "def", a combination of search string T: "efd".

I have found a solution with a run time of O(m*n). I am working on a linear time solution where I used to HashMaps (static one,  maintained for String T, and another a dynamic copy of the previous HashMap used for checking the current substring of T). I'd start checking at the next character where it fails. But this runs in O(m*n) in worst case. 
I'd like to get some pointers to make it work in O(m+n) time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with hash maps in this context. The worst case time for a look up in a typical hash map implementation is linear in the number of elements in the map. All the keys may hash to the same bucket.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would like to know boundaries for string `S` length `(m)` and pattern `T` length `(n)`.

There exist one general idea but complexity of the solution based on it depends on the pattern length. Complexity varies from `O(m)` to `O(m*n^2)` for short patterns with `length<=100` and `O(n)` for long patterns.

[Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) states that every integer number can be uniquely represented as a product of prime numbers.

Idea - I guess, your alphabet is english letters. So, alphabet size is 26. Let's replace first letter with first prime, second letter with the second and so on. I mean the following replacement:
 a->2
b->3
c->5
d->7
e->11 and so on.

Let's denote product of primes corresponding for the letters of some string as `prime product(string)`. For example, `primeProduct(z)` will be `101` as `101` is 26-th prime number, `primeProduct(abc)` will be `2*3*5=30`,`primeProduct(cba)` will also be `5*3*2=30`.

Why we choose prime numbers? If we replace a ->2; b ->3, c->4, we won't be able to decipher for exapmle 4  - is it "c" or "aa".

Solution for the short patterns case:
For the string S, we should calculate in **linear time** prime product for all **prefixes**. I mean we have to create array A such that `A[0] = primeProduct(S[0])`, `A[1] = primeProduct(S[0]S[1])`, `A[N] = primeProduct(S)`. Sample implementation:

```
A[0] = getPrime(S[0]);
for(int i=1;i<S.length;i++)
    A[i]=A[i-1]*getPrime(S[i]);
```

Searching pattern T. Calculate primeProduct(T). For all `'windows'` in S which have the same length with pattern compare it's primeProduct with primeProduct(pattern). If currentWindow is equal to the pattern or currentWindow  is a scrumbled form(anagramm) of the pattern primeProducts will be the same.

Important note! We have prepared array A for **fast computing** primeProduct for **any substring of S**. `primeProduct of(S[i],S[i+1],...S[j])` = `getPrime(S[i])*...*getPrime(S[j])` = `A[j]/A[i-1]`;

Complexity: if pattern length is <=9, even `'zzzzzzzzz'` is `101^9<=MAX_LONG_INT`; All calculations fit in standart long type and complexity is O(N)+O(M) where N is for calculating primeProduct of pattern and M is iterating over all **windows** in `S`. If length<=100 you have to add complexity of mul/div long numbers that's why complexity becomes `O(m*n^2)`. length of 101^length is O(N) mul/div of such long numbers is `O(N^2)`

For the long patterns with length>=1000 it's better to store some hash map(prime,degree). Array of prefixes will become array of hash maps and `A[j]/A[i-1]` trick will become differenceBetween(A[j] and A[i-1] hashmaps's key sets).

Answer (score 1):

Would this JavaScript example be linear time?

```
<script>

function matchT(t,s){
  var tMap = [], answer = []

  //map the character count in t
  for (var i=0; i<t.length; i++){
    var chr = t.charCodeAt(i)

    if (tMap[chr]) tMap[chr]++
    else tMap[chr] = 1
  }

  //traverse string
  for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    if (tMap[s.charCodeAt(i)]){
      var start = i, j = i + 1, tmp = []

      tmp[s.charCodeAt(i)] = 1

      while (tMap[s.charCodeAt(j)]){
        var chr = s.charCodeAt(j++)

        if (tmp[chr]){
          if (tMap[chr] > tmp[chr]) tmp[chr]++
          else break
        }
        else tmp[chr] = 1
      }

      if (areEqual (tmp,tMap)){
        answer.push(start)
        i = j - 1
      }

    }
  }
  return answer
}

//function to compare arrays
function areEqual(arr1,arr2){
  if (arr1.length != arr2.length) return false
  for (var i in arr1)
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) return false
  return true
}

</script>
```

Output:

```
console.log(matchT("edf","ghjfedabcddef"))
[3, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the alphabet is not too large (say, ASCII), then there is no need to use a hash to take care of strings.

Just use a big array which is of the same size as the alphabet, and the existence checking becomes `O(1)`. Thus the whole algorithm becomes `O(m+n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider for the given example,
String S: abcdef 
String T: efd

Create a HashSet which consists of the characters present in the Substring T. So, the set consists of .

Generate a label for the Substring T: **1e1f1d**. (number of occurences of each characters + the character itself, can be done using technique similar to count sort)

Now we have to generate labels for the input of the sub-string's length.

Let us start from the first position, which has character a. Since it is not present we do not create any sub-string and move to the next character b. Similarly, to character c and then stop at d.

Since d is present in the HashSet start generating labels(of the sub-string length) for each time the character appears. We can do this in different function to avoid clearing the count array(doing this reduces the complexity from O(m*n) to O(m+n)). If at any point the input string does not consists of the Substring T we can start the label generation from the next position(since the position till the break occurred cannot be a part of the anagram).

So, by generating the labels we can solve the problem in linear O(m+n) time complexity.

m: length of the input string,
n: length of the sub string.

Answer (score 0):

That Code below I used for the pattern searching questions in GFG its accepted in all test cases and works in linear time.

```html
// { Driver Code Starts
import java.util.*;


class Implement_strstr
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        while(t>0)
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String a = line.split(" ")[0];
            String b = line.split(" ")[1];
            
            GfG g = new GfG();
            System.out.println(g.strstr(a,b));
            
            t--;
        }
    }
}// } Driver Code Ends




class GfG
{
    //Function to locate the occurrence of the string x in the string s.
    int strstr(String a, String d)
    {
      if(a.equals("") && d.equals("")) return 0;
      if(a.length()==1 && d.length()==1 && a.equals(d)) return 0;
        if(d.length()==1 && a.charAt(a.length()-1)==d.charAt(0)) return a.length()-1;
    int t=0;
    int pl=-1;
    boolean b=false;
    int fl=-1;    
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        if(pl!=-1)
        {
            if(i==pl+1 && a.charAt(i)==d.charAt(t))
            {
              t++;
              pl++;
              if(t==d.length())
              {
                  b=true;
                  break;
              }
            }
            else
            {
                fl=-1;
                pl=-1;
                t=0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(a.charAt(i)==d.charAt(t))
            {
                fl=i;
                pl=i;
                t=1;
            }
        }

    }
        return b?fl:-1;
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the question https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/implement-strstr/1

Comment: Hi There. Try formatting your code and also try to explain how it works. Helps people better understand you solution.